# $|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_1|=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_2|$ is the equation of a sphere?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

I am told that the set of all $\vec{r}$ for which $|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_1|=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_2|$ is true forms a sphere---however, my semi-intuitive reading of this equation puts a "weaker weight" on the second vector which would make me think that this should represent an ellipsoid if anything.  I'm not sure of how I would check my thoughts about this, so can anyone confirm what this shape is?  If it's a sphere, how would one figure out its center and radius?

If it's an ellipsoid I would assume that $\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2$ represent focii.

Comment: It's true but it isn't obvious.  This is a classical result due to Apollonius:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give a try. For simplicity, let's work in $\Bbb R^2$ and assume WLOG that $\vec r_2=0$. The equation of the figure would be something like:
$$2(x-a)^2+2(y-b)^2=x^2+y^2$$
or
$$x^2-4ax+2a^2+y^2-4by+2b^2=0$$
which is a circle centered at $(2a,2b)$ and radius $\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2}$.

The general case shouldn't be more difficult.